# Django: A/B test with Google Optmize not working

Tags: django, google-optimize

I'm trying to create an A/B test for my webpage following [this](https://findwork.dev/blog/django-b-testing-google-optimize/) tutorial. I'm using a library called [django-google-optimize](https://github.com/adinhodovic/django-google-optimize) and I've been able to configure it and make it work.

The problem is that the A/B test is for the homepage, and for some reason it never works on the first load. I need to load the page twice in order to see the variant.

Do you have and idea of what am I doing wrong? Could it be possible that this is related to GDPR stuff?

### Update

I created an Issue on GitHub asking the author about this and after a long message exchanging we discovered that there is a bug with the package.

I'll update this entry if the bug gets corrected by either my or the author.

[Here](https://github.com/adinhodovic/django-google-optimize/issues/45) you can check the complete issue.

Comment: It's a pretty new package; I suggest you create an issue in the repository itself (since it's empty). Author will gladly respond. Imo, as someone whose never heard of this, A/B testing in general will try to randomize who gets what. Have you tried accessing the website from multiple devices simultaneously? E.g. you can run multiple private mode tabs or using werkzeug to host on `0.0.0.0:8000` and then use your phone or something to connect to your computer's private IP address at that port and simultaneously test.

Comment: Hi @acw, thank you so much for your reply, it has being super helpful.

I'll do these things you suggest. First, create an issue in GitHub, and then I'll test the webpage with as many devices as I can.

I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Glad to see the author has responded and issue was a bug!

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for remembering me this @acw. I'll share a link to the Issue here.